# Spring Data Rest - Bean Validation is not applied to integer field?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, bean-validation, spring-data-rest

I have the following class defined with bean validation annotations.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Contact{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Min(value=7,message = "Mobile number must have at least 7 digits")
    private int contactNumber;

    @Min(value=7,message = "Mobile number must have at least 7 digits")
    private int mobileNumber;
}
```

However when I post the following JSON to the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/contacts`, it does not throw a constraint violation exception. The post is successful.

```
{
    "contactNumber": 77,
    "mobileNumber" : 77

}
```

So how do I fix this validation?

Comment: And why should it. 77 is larger then 7. `@Min` checks the value not the length of that value.

Comment: Should be `@Min(value=1000000`

Comment: above answer is correct...

Comment: Yeah. That's it. But is there an annotation which could check the length of the integer field

Comment: Try @Size(min=7,max=10)

Comment: @Size will not support integers